# WPF: value is null only in debug for a language resource.

Tags: wpf, debugging, resources, null, release

I'm displaying some texts on my applicaiton. 
Thoses text are stored in a resource file.
When I run my application on Release mode, all the texts are correctly loaded, but when I try to run on Debug mode, some of the texts' value are nulls.

Exemple:

```
MySpaceName.Resources.Language.Resources.message_loadimages_error //(is null)
MySpaceName.Resources.Language.Resources.message_loadimages_error_title //(is correctly loaded, not null)
```

message_loadimages_error is correctly set on my application:

```
<data name="message_loadimages_error" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Error while loading images...</value>
</data>
```

And in the .cs:

```
/// <summary>
///   Recherche une chaîne localisée semblable à Error while loading images...
/// </summary>
public static string message_loadimages_error {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("message_loadimages_error", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try Rebuild All? That's the first thing to do when you encounter strange problems :)

Comment: Yes, I tried Rebuild All, but nothing changes.